# Generated Artifacts via JAXB fail to parse the log.xml

Tags: java, jaxb, log4j

I am trying to generate artifacts for `log4j` XML parsing using `JAXB`. I am using the dtd

> http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/ap.../log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd

and inlined log.xml. I am getting below exception. I am a newbie with all these tech. Please someone help with this issue.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
>   unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/",
>   local:"configuration"). Expected
>   elements are
>   <{}appender>,<{}appender-ref>,<{}category>,<{}categoryFactory>,<{}connectionSource>,<{}dataSource>,<{}errorHandler>,<{}filter>,<{}layout>,<{}level>,<{}logger>,<{}logger-ref>,<{}loggerFactory>,<{}param>,<{}plugin>,<{}priority>,<{}renderer>,<{}rollingPolicy>,<{}root>,<{}root-ref>,<{}triggeringPolicy>
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:558)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:211)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:206)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:83)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:965)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:401)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:382)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:113)
>   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:202)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
>   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:148)
>   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:153)
>   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
>   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:180)

**log4jXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT"/>
    </appender>


    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x- %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DEFAULT" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File"   value="/home/default.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x- %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="DB_EXCEP" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File"   value="/home/db_exception.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x- %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="com.common.db.ScriptRunner" additivity="false">
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="DB_EXCEP" />
    </category>


    <category name="com.common.appsvr.current.admin" additivity="false">
        <priority value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT"/>
    </category>

    <!-- ROOT CATEGORY -->
    <root>
        <priority value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT"/>
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>  -->
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

The problem with my original answer was due to a formatting error in your question.  Originally the root element was not visible (corrected now), so I thought you had provided 7 sample documents instead of one document with 7 sub elements :).

The log4j.dtd defines element names with a colon in them, this is confusing the JAXB implementation if its underlying parser is set to namespace aware since it thinks that the element `log4j:configuration` is really an element named `configuration` in the namespace `http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/`.

The solution is to force the JAXB implementation to use a non-namespace-aware parser:

```
package log4j;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.UnmarshallerHandler;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("log4j");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream("src/log4j/file1.xml");
        InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(xmlStream);
        xr.parse(xmlSource);

        Log4JConfiguration config = (Log4JConfiguration) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(config, System.out);
    }

}
```

---

Here is what I did that worked:

**Obtain log4j.dtd**

From the [log4j download](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) I noticed that there were 3 log4j.dtd files, the one I used was in:

```
<log4j_home>/source/main/resources/org/apache/log4j/xml
```

**Run XJC**

Since we are using XJC on a DTD file and not an XML schema we need to specify the `-dtd` flag:

```
xjc -p log4j -d out -dtd log4j.dtd
```

**Create the JAXBContext**

Next I create the JAXBContext on the `log4j` package that I used XJC to generate:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("log4j");
```

**Demo Code**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("log4j");

        processXML(jc,"src/log4j/file1.xml");
        processXML(jc,"src/log4j/file2.xml");
        processXML(jc,"src/log4j/file3.xml");
        processXML(jc,"src/log4j/file4.xml");
        processXML(jc,"src/log4j/file5.xml");
        processXML(jc,"src/log4j/file6.xml");
        processXML(jc,"src/log4j/file7.xml");
    }

    private static void processXML(JAXBContext jc, String fileName) throws Exception {
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(fileName));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(o, System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import log4j.*;


public class Me {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        JAXBContext js = JAXBContext.newInstance("log4j");
        Unmarshaller u = js.createUnmarshaller();
        Object xmlConf = u.unmarshal(new File("log.xml"));

        Marshaller m = js.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(xmlConf, new FileOutputStream("out.xml"));



    }
}